# How to pivot this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

In my case I have table with data are like that:

```
error_id|role_id|
--------+-------+
       6|1;4;5  |
       7|3;2    |
```

How can i change this table to this:

```
error_id|role_id|
--------+-------+
       6|1      |
       6|4      |
       6|5      |
       7|3      |
       7|2      |
```

I will be very glad if you have any idea

Comment: You should normalize your data before you bring it into SQL Server.

Comment: Personally, I'd query the existing table & write a PHP script (since I'm proficient in PHP) to generate the SQL needed to get the new format.

Answer (score 3):

Small task using a `CROSS APPLY` and `string_split()`

```
Select A.error_id
      ,role_id = B.Value
  From YourTable A
  Cross Apply string_split(role_id,';') B
```